# « Aller chez Leclerc » ou « Aller à Leclerc »

Tags: grammaire, expressions, noms-propres, jargon

J'ai tendance à dire « Aller **à** Leclerc », comme je dirais « aller **à** Auchan » et « aller **chez** le coiffeur ».
Le « chez » étant pour moi réservé au lieu d'une personne et non d'une entité.

Par contre, on entend très souvent (publicité, journalistes,…) utiliser l'expression « aller **chez** *telle enseigne* ».

Y a-t-il une règle qui spécifie qu'il est possible d'employer cette expression dans le cas d'une enseigne, ou toute autre entité, ou est-ce juste un abus (ce qui serait très dommage selon moi) ?

Comment: Est-ce que tu as aussi tendance à dire « au jour d'aujourd'hui », les jours où tu vas à au champ ? :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sans avoir consulté d'autorité ou de corpus, je dirais qu'on utilise *chez* pour une personne (nommée ou non) ou une enseigne, et *à* pour un magasin particulier.

> Je vais à la boulangerie. (Je vais chez le boulanger.)
>   Je vais chez le coiffeur. Je vais au salon de coiffure.
>   J'ai acheté cet object chez Carrefour. J'ai acheté cet object au Carrefour du coin.
>   Je vais à l'épicerie. Je vais chez Duval.

Entre « chez Leclerc » et « à Leclerc », je pense que le premier désigne l'enseigne en général, tandis que le second désigne un magasin particulier. Bien souvent, la distinction est immatérielle et on peut donc utiliser indifféremment l'un ou l'autre.

De plus, lorsque le magasin particulier n'est pas spécifié, la phrase peut s'appliquer à tout magasin du groupe. Pour des magasins uniques ou qui ont un site phare, je trouve *chez* carrément étrange, l'utiliser insisterait lourdement sur l'entreprise par opposition au magasin.

> (Cet article est disponible chez Fnac.) Cet article est disponible à la Fnac.
>   Je vais au Bon Marché.
>   Je vais au BHV.

(Entre parenthèses, des phrases qui me semblent correctes mais inhabituelles.)

Answer (score 2):

Leclerc est d'abord un nom propre avec enseigne éponyme, d'où la difficulté.

J'utilise parfois :

> - "je vais *au*  Leclerc du coin", sous entendu au magasin, mais plus facilement "*chez* Leclerc" du fait que j'ai vu des reportages sur l'histoire de la famille en question.
> - "tu as   trouvé ça *chez* Leclerc?" difficulté d'oreille pour remplacer par *à* ou *au* qui me semblent très familiers.

C'est la proximité où l'on se trouve, de l'enseigne ou du créateur lui ayant donné son nom, qui favorise le choix.
Si d'évidence on ignore l'origine de la marque, employer *à* n'a rien de choquant, sinon je ne connais pas de règle officielle.

Comment: Je te remercie pour cette réponse. Donc tu dirais quoi pour Carrefour, Auchan, Norauto, ... ? J'ai l'impression que c'est un peu au libre choix alors qu'il me semble bien qu'il faille toujours dire "à" pour des magasins. Par contre, je suis tout à fait d'accord avec toi.

Answer (score 0):

Ce n'est pas un abus. Au contraire. On peut dire *aller à Leclerc* et *aller chez Leclerc*, mais on ne peut pas dire *aller au coiffeur*. *Aller chez Leclerc* est un peu plus soutenu, plus joli, cela personnalise l'enseigne. D'autant plus que Leclerc est le nom du fondateur. Mais on dit aussi *aller chez Auchan*.